# VB script to identify missing mandatory cell values across different rows and columns in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel file contains 20 columns and 100 rows, If the Value in A2= Reportable certain columns in excel are mandatory and similarly if A2 =Non-Reportable then certain other column values are mandatory, So need an VB script to check this condition if any of the mandatory column cell value is blank then on save of excel file throw an error message and error message should list all the missing column headers and rows. The script should validate all the rows, tried the below code, but not working and also i get mutiple error message instead of single error message

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim flag As Boolean
    flag = False
    If Cells(1, 1) = "" Then flag = True
    For Each Cell In Range("B2:B3")
    If Cell = "" Then
    MsgBox ("Signoff is missing")
    flag = True
    Exit For
    End If
    Next Cell
    For Each Cell In Range("D2:D3")
    If Cell = "" Then
    MsgBox ("tax Regime value is missing")
   flag = True
   Exit For
  End If
   Next Cell
  For Each Cell In Range("E2:E3")
  If Cell = "" Then
  MsgBox ("Classification value is missing")
  flag = True
  Exit For
   End If
  Next Cell

   Cancel = flag

End Sub
```

Comment: You don't seem to be checking the value of A2?  If you only want a single msgbox, build up a string with all of the errors, then check at the end to see if its length is >0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update - added error.txt as output

update2 - colour cells red and create error sheet

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim ws As Worksheet, lastrow As Long, ar(2)
    Dim msg As String, c As String
    Dim r As Long, i As Long, n As Long
    
    ar(1) = Array("B", "D", "F") ' non-reportable columns
    ar(2) = Array("C", "E", "G") ' reportable columns
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    With ws
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 2 To lastrow
            .Rows(r).Cells.Interior.Pattern = xlNone
            n = 0
            If LCase(.Cells(r, "A")) = "non-reportable" Then
                n = 1
            ElseIf LCase(.Cells(r, "A")) = "reportable" Then
                n = 2
            End If
            If n > 0 Then
                For i = 0 To UBound(ar(n))
                    c = ar(n)(i)
                    If .Cells(r, c) = "" Then
                        .Cells(r, c).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' red
                        msg = msg & vbLf & "Row " & r & " missing " & .Cells(1, c)
                    End If
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
     
    Dim wsErr As Worksheet, arErr
    If Len(msg) > 0 Then
    
        ' create error sheet
        arErr = Split(msg, vbLf)
        Set wsErr = Sheets.Add(after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))
        wsErr.Name = "Errors " & Format(Now(), "yyyy-mm-dd hhmmss")
        wsErr.Cells(1, 1).Resize(UBound(arErr) + 1) = Application.Transpose(arErr)
    
        Open "errors.txt" For Output As #1
        Print #1, msg
        Close #1
        MsgBox "Missing data see error.txt", vbCritical
        Cancel = True
    Else
        MsgBox "All good"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you, But i am getting an error saying "Invalid outside procedure" in the above code.  Can you kindly help me what should be corrected.

Comment: @basha check there is no codelines outside the Sub to End Sub lines except the Option Explicit. Maybe you have a comment missing a `'`

Comment: Thank you for your response, There is no codelines outside Sub and End Sub lines and Comment  word is having '  but still getting the same error "Invalid outside procedure".

Comment: @basha Which line does the compiler highlight ?

Comment: Its working now, Thank you so much for your help, But only issue is if there are 100rows if multiple values are missing then error popup message is 1. shown only for first 15 rows and remaining rows are missing in error message 2. Error message is  very lengthy anything we can customize the error message user friendly.

Comment: @basha see update - i have written the message box to a file called errors.txt. You could highlight the missing cells if that helps.

Comment: Along with the error text file, is it possible to highlight the mandatory blank cell in Red colour in the same code, Kindly advise  @ CD1802

Comment: Error messages are shown in txt file i want the error in an new worksheet under the same file, how this can be done.

Comment: @basha Do you want the errors sheet in a new workbook, or create a sheet in the workbook being closed. It would be easier if there is an existing sheet called something like  "Validation" or "Errors" in the existing workbook.

Comment: Thanks for responding me -- I need the errors in a new worksheet under the same file i.e Example i have file name called Template where my validations get checked once the validations checks are done the error list should be created in an new worksheet in the same excel file on save or cancel, IF possible also i want to highlight all the missing mandatory cells in color in my worksheet- Template, kindly advise if this can be done

Comment: @basha Ok see update